# Fonts display oddly on OS X Mavericks

Tags: firefox, fonts

In the last few days OS X Mavericks has started behaving strangely; well, with regard to one font anyway - Consolas.

It displays fine in InDesign and in Terminal, but as italic in Firefox (tested a CSS page) even though the regular font Consolas is installed.

This site shows it as italics; Safari does not.

I cleared caches, restarted OS X, but it still shows italic font.

It's a small problem, but slightly irritating nonetheless.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I am seeing this in my Atom editor as well. What gives.  Consolas specifically.